# Problems with colorschemes after upgrading to Debian Stretch (vim 8.0)

Tags: vim

I had Debian 8 system with vim 7.4 and two days ago I upgraded to Debian 9. Vim was upgraded to 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 23 2017 12:10:29)Included patches: 1-197, 322, 377-378, 550

The issue is that the background of a color scheme "drops" to the background color of the terminal after scrolling down (if the text is longer than the screen).

[image]

On this screenshot gray is the background color of vim colorscheme and dark-blue is the background of my terminal.

If I go to visual mode and select part of the text, then deselect it, background will be "fixed" for that portion of the text.

The situation is the same in Gnome3, Mate and i3 and it's the same in gnome-terminal and mate-terminal.

Is there a solution for this that wouldn't involve building custom colorscheme with the same background color as my terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, adding:

```
    set t_ut=
```

to ~/.vimrc solved the problem.

Comment: You can accept also your own answer, we like self-answers.